# Java int variable to pass to Javascript function

Tags: javascript

How to send Java integer variable value to Javascript function on click event

I tried:

```
onclick="enableFinanceField('<%=i%>')
```

but its taking it as string where `i` is `int` here.

Complete source code:

```
<html:checkbox 
     name="FinanceLoForm"
     property="checksrnochkbx"
     styleId="<%=checkbxindx%>" 
     value="<%=dataScript%>"  
     onclick="enableFinanceField(<%=i%>);
     enableDisableSave('tbl_setup',th‌​is.form);"> 

</html:checkbox>
```

Comment: enableFinanceField(<%=i%>); ?

Comment: Please show us the code, we can help you better if you show us more of the code

Comment: <% int i %>   <html:checkbox name="FinanceLoForm" 
            property="checksrnochkbx" styleId="<%=checkbxindx%>"
            value="<%=dataScript%>" 
            onclick="enableFinanceField(<%=i%>);enableDisableSave('tbl_setup',this.form);">           
I want to pass i (declared in scriptlet function) to enableFinanceField method.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the single quotes and pass it like this

```
onclick="enableFinanceField(<%=i%>)
```

Or you can explicitly convert it to number using the `parseInt()` JavaScript function.

The syntax will be something like this

```
onclick="enableFinanceField(parseInt('<%=i%>'));
```

Comment: @user3568379: Hi and Welcome to SO,when writhing details about the questions please be more descriptive,As far as I can understand this piece of code is form a JSP page right?

Comment: @user3568379: If inside the `enableFinanceField` function you are getting the string value , you can alternately use the `parseInt` function there to convert it to integer.

Comment: But what is the syntax while passing the parameter. I tried enableFinanceField('<%=i%>') but its not working. also enableFinanceField(<%=i%>) gives syntax error.

Comment: @user3568379: its not actually Java's fault , but rather JavaScript is loosely typed so its taking this value as String. Just convert it to number using `parseInt()` inside the function. Some sample code can be found here http://jsfiddle.net/vpGgE/